# How to get latest data for a column when using grouping in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using postgres alongside sequelize. I have encountered a case where I need to write a coustom query which groups the records are a particular field. I know for the remaning columns that are not used for grouping, I need to use a aggregate function like `SUM`. But the problem is that for some columns I need to get the one what is the latest one (DESC sorted by `created_at`). I see no function in sql to do so. Is my only option to write subqueries or is there a better way? Thanks?

For better understanding, If you look at the below picture, I want the group the records with `address`. So after the query there should only be two records, one with `sydney` and the other with `new york`. But when it comes to the distance, I want the result of the query to contain the distance form the row that was most recently created, i.e with the latest `created_at`.

so the final two query results should be:

```
sydney   100   2022-09-05 18:14:53.492131+05:45
new york  40     2022-09-05 18:14:46.23328+05:45
```

[image]

Comment: Please add example of table, if table have date column, you can use row_number()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select address, distance, created_at
from(
        select address, distance, created_at, row_number() over(partition by address order by created_at DESC) as rn
        from table) x
    where rn = 1
```

Comment: I have updates the question body. Hope it helps you to understand my problem. :)

Comment: @sammanadhikari check now, I edited. but I need more info about your results, need be grouped, or only you need latest address

Comment: well, The result needs to be grouped. In real codebase there are other fields, for which I have used the SUM aggregator function. This is the only field where I need the data form the most recent row.

Comment: so you tried this ?

Comment: Hey, it works thanks. I just miss read it the first time and didn't think it was going to work. my bad.